# Too Many redirects in Facebook Login with Phalcon

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, phalcon

We have a problem with facebook authentication. We use phalcon and we have the authentication process with the php-sdk-v4 plugin. When we try to login, we have the error of too many redirects. Our website is https://app.wowego.com/register. some help?

CODE:
FILE: AUTH.PHP

```
public function loginWithFacebook()
{
    $di = $this->getDI();
    $facebook = new FacebookConnector($di);

    $facebookUser = $facebook->getUser();
    if (!$facebookUser) {
        $scope = [
            'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,user_location',
        ];

        return $this->response->redirect($facebook->getLoginUrl($scope), true);
    }
    try {
        return $this->authenticateOrCreateFacebookUser($facebookUser);
    } catch (\FacebookApiException $e) {
        $di->logger->begin();
        $di->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        $di->logger->commit();
        $facebookUser = null;
    }
}
```

FACEBOOKCONNECTOR.PHP

```
public function __construct($di)
{

    $this->di = $di;
    $fbConfig = $di->get('config')->pup->connectors->facebook;

    $protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], '/'))).'://';
    $protocol="https://";

    if (isset($fbConfig['route'])) {
        $this->url = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$fbConfig['route'];
    } else {
        $this->url = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/usercontrol/loginwithfacebook';
    }
    //echo $this->url;die();


    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($fbConfig->appId, $fbConfig->secret);
}

public function getLoginUrl($scope = [])
{
    $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($this->url);

    return $this->helper->getLoginUrl($scope);
}

/**
 * Get facebook user details.
 *
 * @return unknown|bool
 */
public function getUser()
{
    try {
        $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($this->url);
        $this->fb_session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        $this->di->get('flashSession')->error($ex->getMessage());
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->di->get('flashSession')->error($ex->getMessage());
    }

    if ($this->fb_session) {
        $request = new FacebookRequest($this->fb_session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $fb_user = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        return $fb_user;
    }

    return false;
}
```

USERCONTROLLER.PHP

```
public function loginwithfacebookAction()
{
    try {
        //echo "dentro del try";
        $this->view->disable();
        $fopen = fopen('../logs/loginWithFacebook.log');
        fwrite( $this->auth->loginWithFacebook() , $fopen );
        fclose( $fopen );
        return $this->auth->loginWithFacebook();
    } catch(AuthException $e) {
        $this->flash->error('There was an error connectiong to Facebook.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, you expect help without any code, configuration or logs?

Comment: sorry i post code

Comment: Nobody wants to download someone's (incorrect code) file. Use editor and write code right here. You will have more chance for getting applicable answer that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't test it, but it seems to be circular: in `facebookconnector.php` the if leads to the same call to the static function `FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication`. You may try:

```
if (isset($fbConfig['route'])) {
    $this->url = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$fbConfig['route'];
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($fbConfig->appId, $fbConfig->secret);
} else {
    $this->url = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/usercontrol/loginwithfacebook';
    return $this->response->redirect($this->url);
}
```